# How to open Android Studio on Kali Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio successfully but I don't know how to open it.
I give hard effort for open it on its own folder but i didn't find anything in its destination

I tried every file to open it, but it did not work.

Comment: Use the terminal... `sh /path/to/studio.sh`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/639260/run-android-studio-after-installation-and-other-programs

Comment: or you can do what @cricket_007 said :P ahahhaa

Comment: Honestly, Kali isn't designed as a Linux for beginners, so it's not clear why you need it. At least for Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new, I recommend install synaptic:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

after install it run it:

```
sudo synaptic
```

and then type there `android`, and the program will be listed

Comment: You could also `apt-cache search android` to get the same results

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it's true, also it will help to getting accustomed to the user to use more the terminal, maybe is better your way now I think...

Comment: Thank you so much guys @cricket_007

Comment: @tbcse no prob! don't forget to accept the answer, with the check box top left ;), and voting if you liked :)

Answer (score 3):

sudo sh /path_installed/android/bin/studio.sh

Answer (score 2):

You could add an alias for android, to run it from the terminal. Open the .bashrc file and type in 
`alias android="sh path/to/studio.sh"` 
and save it. Restart the terminal or source the bash by typing
`source .bashrc`. 
When you want to start android, just type in android from the terminal.